Prevent RadioButtonGroup's value from resetting to -1 on redraw
Using Unity 6 UI Toolkit, I have a RadioButtonGroup which I have a "Two Way" binding on the value property (to an integer) and a "To Target" binding on the choices.
Whenever the RadioButtonGroup is redrawn (due to a option being selected or a state changing), the value property is reset to -1 then immediately set back to what my binding variable is (what I selected). Visually nothing changes, but this double setting of the value means it goes into an infinite loop of redrawing itself as the -1 requires a redraw then the setting back to actual value is a redraw which triggers it to go back to -1 and so on.
Why does it do this and how do I prevent it?
